# Python GCP Cloud function connecting to Cloud SQL Error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.sql'"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am creating a cloud function to retrieve data from a source and load into my gcp mysql instance. It is configured on the same VPC network and I gave the proper IAM roles to the Cloud SQL instance as well as my cloud function.

The requirements.txt:

```
    certifi==2022.12.7
    charset-normalizer==3.0.1
    idna==3.4
    mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
    protobuf==3.20.3
    requests==2.28.2
    urllib3==1.26.14
    cloud-sql-python-connector==1.2.0
    PyMySQL==1.0.2
```

The connection snippet of my function:

```
    def _get_connection(db= 'bot_config')-> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
 

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE

    connector = Connector(ip_type)

    conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
        'x:y:z',
        "pymysql",
        user='user',#not actually...
        password='password', #not actually...
        db=db,
    )
    return conn
```

and the import I have:

```
    import requests
    import os

    from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
    import pymysql

    import sqlalchemy
```

I also get this error along with the one in the title:

```
    OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

I would optimally like to use mysql.connector, but this is what I saw in documentation. If major suspect is the VPC or IAM I can share that.

I've configured the VPC and IAM correctly and used the write connector object as reccomended through documentation. Not sure why my packages can't be found, especially the google one.